# Backbone: Re-render existing model in new DOM element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using a collection view to render my array of model views.  I have added a method that removes a single model view from the existing collection view, and attempts to re-render it in a new el: element.

I use `collection.get(this.model)` to save the model to a variable, I add that variable to my new collection which is the model of a new collection view associated with a new DOM element, and I re-use the same collection view render method.  When I console.log() the new collection, I see the model that I picked from the old collection, but it's not rendering on the page.

```
<script>

    (function($){

    //---------SINGLE ENTRY MODEL----------
            var Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: function(){
                    return{
                        word: '',
                        definition: ''
                    }
                }
            });

        //------------ENTRY MODEL COLLECTION------------
            var EntryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Entry
            });

        //-----INSTANCIATE COLLECTION----
        var dictionary = new EntryList();
        var saved = new EntryList();

        //-----SINGLE ENTRY VIEW------
        var EntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: new Entry(),
            tagName:'div',

            events:{
                'click .edit': 'edit',
                'click .delete': 'delete',
                'keypress .definition': 'updateOnEnter',
                'click .save': 'save'
            },

            delete: function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault;
                dictionary.remove(this.model);

            },

            edit: function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault;
                this.$('.definition').attr('contenteditable', true).focus();

            },
            //method that adds existing model to new collection
            save: function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault;
                var savedEntry = dictionary.get(this.model);
                dictionary.remove(this.model);
                saved.add(savedEntry);
                console.log(savedEntry.toJSON());

            },
            close: function(){
                var definition = this.$('.definition').text();
                this.model.set('definition', definition);
                this.$('.definition').attr('contenteditable', false).blur();

            },

            updateOnEnter: function(ev){
                if(ev.which == 13){
                    this.close();
                }
            },

            initialize: function(){
                this.template = _.template($("#dictionary_template").html());

            },

            render: function(){
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });

        //--------------DICTIONARY VIEW------------
        var DictionaryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: dictionary,
            el: $('#entries'),

            initialize: function(){
                this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
                this.model.on('remove', this.render, this);

            },

            render: function(){
                var self = this;
                self.$el.html('');
                _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(entry, i){
                    self.$el.append((new EntryView({model: entry})).render().$el);
                });

                return this;
            }
        });

        //---------SAVED ENTRY VIEW-----------
        var SavedView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: saved,
            el: $('#saved'),

            initialize: function(){
                this.model.on('save', this.savedRender, this);
            },
            //method that renders new collection view with different el: 
            savedRender: function(){
                var self = this;
                self.$el.html('');
                _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(saved, i){
                    self.$el.append((new EntryView({model: savedEntry})).render().$el);
                });

                return this;
            }
        });


        //-------BINDING DATA ENTRY TO NEW MODEL VIEW-------
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#new-entry').submit(function(ev){
                var entry = new Entry({word: $('#word').val(), definition: $('#definition').val()       });

                dictionary.add(entry);
                dictionary.comparator = 'word';

                console.log(dictionary.toJSON());

                $('.form-group').children('input').val('');

                return false;
            });
            var appView = new DictionaryView();
        });


        //--------------ROUTER----------------
        var Router =  Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes:{
                '':'home' 
            }
        });
        var router = new Router();
        router.on('route:home', function(){
            console.log('router home');
        });
        Backbone.history.start();
    })(jQuery); 

    </script>
```

Comment: What is the point in defining the Entry model's `defaults` property as a function that returns an object literal rather than just assigning the object directly (`defaults: { ... }`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

First, you do not have an instance of `SavedView`. The `var SavedView = Backbone.View.extend(...);` statement is just defining the `SavedView` *class*. In order to have a living instance of this class, you must initialize one with the `new` operator. You will need a line like the following somewhere in your code (a good place would be at the end of the jQuery ready handler):

```
var saved_view = new SavedView();
```

Next, we will investigate the save method of the `EntryView` class. The `var savedEntry = dictionary.get(this.model);` statement is completely unnecessary because we know that `dictionary.get(this.model)` will return this.model - which we obviously already have an instance of. So we can remove the clutter from this method and be left with the following:

```
ev.preventDefault;
saved.add(this.model);
dictionary.remove(this.model);
```

However, we are still not at our destination. If we turn our attention to the `SavedView` class definition, we see that it is binding its render method to the 'save' event on its collection, the `saved` object. Its not the 'save' event we should be binding to, but rather the 'add' event - as that is what will be triggered when we *add* models to `saved`:

```
this.model.on('add', this.savedRender, this);
```

If we test our code now we should get scolded with a reference error on `savedEntry` within `SavedView.savedRender`. It looks like this is a typo and what was intended was `saved'. (You will notice below that in addition to correcting the typo, I have also removed a set of parentheses from this expression that served no function save for making the code less readable):

```
self.$el.append(new EntryView({ model: saved }).render().$el);
```

EDIT:

In response to your follow-up question about the `saved` variable inside the `SavedView.savedRender` method:

The `saved` object in this case *is* a single Entry model. The reason for your confusion is that we are re-using the variable name "saved". Within the _.each callback we have defined the first parameter to be called "saved"; this "saved" is local to the callback and is not related to the `EntryList` collection defined previously. Within our callback, `saved` is an element of the `saved` collection (yikes!) - which is a lesson in why variable naming is important.

As I proceeded to change the name of "saved" in the `savedRender` method, I noticed a few other refactorings that were screaming to be made. I have listed my refactorings below:

1. A purpose of using Backbone (http://backbonejs.org/) is to give us access to convenient helpers for objects (models) and arrays (collections). Backbone collections have an `each` method we can make use of instead of passing our collection to Underscore's (http://underscorejs.org/) `each`.
2. As stated above, `saved` is a terrible name for our `each` callback parameter because it conflicts conceptually with the name of the collection. Because `saved` is a collection of Entry models, "entry" is a much more suitable name.
3. Backbone allows us to pass the context to our each callback that will be our `this` within that callback. This allows us to skip the step of caching our `this` in the `self` variable.

My refactored `savedRender` becomes:

```
savedRender: function () {    
    this.$el.empty();
    this.model.each(function (entry) {
        this.$el.append(new EntryView({ model: entry }).render().$el);
    }, this);    

    return this;
}
```

Comment: how are we able to use a collection model to render a single view in the case of SavedView?  In my DictionaryView I use model:entry, but in the SavedView we used model:saved (a collection).

Comment: @redress: `saved` *is* a single entry when we are inside of the each iterator callback because we have assigned this name to our iteratee. Your question emphasizes why this is a poor naming choice. See the edit (appendage) to my answer.

Comment: ok so in the `render` method for the `DictionaryView`, my `entry` as an iterator just so happens to be the same name as the collection's model?

Comment: @redress: I would not say that it "just so happens". You, as the author of the callback function, have deliberately chosen a name for the parameter. I would say that "entry" is a good choice because the model items in the `dictionary` collection are instances of the Entry model object that you defined. But you are free to choose almost anything (so long as it's a valid identifier).